# How do I add a composite foreign key in sequelize?

Tags: node.js, express, sequelize.js

I have defined the following tables, archive and infos. Each file can have many information tags. The combination of field and tag is unique. For this I require a composite primary key consisting of field and tag. field refers to field in the archive table. The model definitions are given below.

Archive table:

```js
    module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
      let archive = sequelize.define('archive', {
        fileid: {
          type: DataTypes.STRING,
          primaryKey: true,
          allowNull: false
        },
        filename: {
          type: DataTypes.STRING,
          unique: false,
          allowNull: false
        },
        originalname: {
          type: DataTypes.STRING,
          unique: false,
          allowNull: false
        },
        downloadlink: {
          type: DataTypes.STRING,
          unique: false,
          allowNull: false
        },
        domain: {
          type: DataTypes.STRING,
          unique: false,
          allowNull: false
        },
        sem: {
          type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
          unique: false,
          allowNull: false
        },
        branch: {
          type: DataTypes.STRING,
          unique: false,
          allowNull: false
        }
      });
      archive.associate = models => {
        models.archive.hasMany(models.info, {
          foreignKey: 'fileid'
        });
        models.archive.hasMany(models.upvotes, {
          foreignKey: 'fileid'
        });
      };
      return archive;
    };
```

Info Table

```js
    module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
      let info = sequelize.define('info', {
        tag: {
          type: DataTypes.STRING,
          allowNull: false,
          primaryKey: true
        }
      });
      info.associate = models => {
        models.info.belongsTo(models.archive, {
          foreignKey: 'fileid',
          primaryKey: true
        });
      };
      return info;
    };
```

Making the primaryKey: true did not work. I have tried through: as well. I cannot seem to make it work.

Answer (score 1):

Sequelize can be a giant pain.  I follow the docs to the letter and still things don't work with some of the more complex queries, such as can be the case with `composite primary key`.  My suggestion to you is when you bump in to `Model fails`, go with Raw queries.  That being said still take the extra steps to protect against SQL injection attacks.

here is an example:

1. ensure that you include `type`
2. santize variables (in this case `code`)

```js
   db.sequelize
      .query('SELECT count(*) FROM logs WHERE code = :code ', {
         replacements: {
            code: code
         },
         type: Sequelize.QueryTypes.SELECT
      })
      .then((data) => {
        ...
      })
      .catch((err) => {
       ...
      });
```

I would have posted this a comment but there was not enough space.